# Pool apply function hangs and never executes

Tags: python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager, pyral

I am trying to fetch Rally data by using its python library pyral. Sequentially the same code works, but its slow.
I thought of using python multiprocess package, however my pool.apply method gets stuck and never executes. I tried running it in Pycharm IDE as well as the windows cmd prompt.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyral import Rally
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from pyral.entity import Project


def process_row(sheetHeaders: list, item: Project, L: list):
    print('processing row : ' + item.Name)  ## this print never gets called
    row = ()
    for header in sheetHeaders:
        row.append(process_cell(header, item))
    L.append(row)


def process_cell(attr, item: Project):
    param = getattr(item, attr)
    if param is None:
        return None
    try:
        if attr == 'Owner':
            return param.__getattr__('Name')
        elif attr == 'Parent':
            return param.__getattr__('ObjectID')
        else:
            return param
    except KeyError as e:
        print(e)

# Projects
# PortfolioItem
# User Story
# Hierarchical Req
# tasks
# defects

# -------------MAIN-----------------


def main():
    # Rally connection
    rally = Rally('rally1.rallydev.com', apikey='<my_key>')
    file = 'rally_data.xlsx'
    headers = {
        'Project': ['Name', 'Description', 'CreationDate', 'ObjectID', 'Parent', 'Owner', 'State'],
    }
    sheetName = 'Project'
    sheetHeaders = headers.get(sheetName)
    p = Pool(1)
    result = rally.get(sheetName, fetch=True, pagesize=10)
    with Manager() as manager:
        L = manager.list()
        for item in result:
            print('adding row for : ' + item.Name)
            p.apply_async(func=process_row, args=(sheetHeaders, item, L)) ## gets stuck here
        p.close()
        p.join()
        pd.DataFrame(L).to_excel(file, sheet_name=sheetName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also tried without Manager list without any difference in the outcome

```
def main():
    # Rally connection
    rally = Rally('rally1.rallydev.com', apikey='<key>')
    file = 'rally_data.xlsx'
    headers = {
        'Project': ['Name', 'Description', 'CreationDate', 'ObjectID', 'Parent', 'Owner', 'State'],
    }
    sheetName = 'Project'
    sheetHeaders = headers.get(sheetName)
    result = rally.get(sheetName, fetch=True, pagesize=10)
    async_results = []
    with Pool(50) as p:
        for item in result:
            print('adding row for : ' + item.Name)
            async_results.append(p.apply_async(func=process_row, args=(sheetHeaders, item)))
    res = [r.get() for r in async_results]
    pd.DataFrame(res).to_excel(file, sheet_name=sheetName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but replacing `multiprocessing`
with `multiprocessing.dummy` in the import statement worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For starters, [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) is the threads-equivalent. It is the same API of multiprocessing but as a wrapper on the `threading` module. As to why that solves your problem I'm also not sure as your question is not very clear and lacks a [mre]